# Selenium(Python) wait 10 sec for searching id on the page

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriverwait

I have some example of the code:

```
def wait_for_id(self, id):
    self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, id)))
    return self.browser.find_element_by_id(id)
```

I need to wait only 10 sec for finding this element on the page. If it will be more than 10 sec, so need to fail and continue next row.

```
self.wait_for_id('quit').click()
```

So by default, there is a time for waiting is 30 minutes(around this time)... then it failed as I expected, but I want to put for example only 2 minutes maximum on waiting for failure.

Comment: You can pass a timeout parameter to `WebDriverWait`, which is what I assume your `self.wait` is.

Answer (score 1):

The [`WebDriverWait()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#selenium.webdriver.support.wait.WebDriverWait) constructor  takes a WebDriver instance and timeout in seconds.

So essentially before the following code block:

```
def wait_for_id(self, id): 
    self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, id))) 
    return self.browser.find_element_by_id(id)
```

somewhere in your code you have defined *`wait`* as:

```
self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 1800)
```

Hence, time for waiting is 30 minutes.

To reduce the waiting time to ***2 minutes*** you need to change it as:

```
self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 120)
```